# How to convert nested for loop with extra command to java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a nested for loop.  Every message class have relation to MessageDetail class (one to many relation) and  I want to convert below for loop to stream.

```
for (Message m:messages){
        System.out.println(m.getText());
        for (MessageDetail m2:m.getMessageDetails()){
            System.out.println(m2.getId+m2.getStatus());
        }
    }
```

I try this code but i can not show e.getText in upper level.

```
messages.stream().flatMap(e-> e.getMessageDetails().stream().map(
                e2->e.getText()+"-->{"+e2.getId()+"," +e2.getStatus()+"}"
                )).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The output like:

```
[
 Hi-->{1,OK},
 Hi-->{2,OK},
 Hi-->{4,NOT_DELIVER},
 Bye-->{5,OK},
 Bye-->{6,NOT_DELIVER},
 Bye-->{7,NOT_DELIVER},
]
```

But I want to like this:

```
  [
    Hi [ {2,OK},{3,OK},{4,NOT_DELIVER}]
    Bye[ {5,OK},{6,NOT_DELIVER},{7,NOT_DELIVER}]
  ]
```

Comment: `messages.stream().flatMap(e-> { System.out.println(e.getText()); return e.getMessageDetails().stream();}).map(
                    e->e.getStatus()+e.getMessage()).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flatMap` should be used only when you want each element in your stream to transform into multiple elements in the resulting stream. Here, each `Message` in the original stream correspond to one `String` in the resulting list, so you should not use `flatMap`.

Use `map` instead:

```
messages.stream().map(
    e -> e.getText() + "-->" + 
        e.getMessageDetails().stream().map(d -> "{" + d.getId() + ", " + d.getStatus() + "}").collect(Collectors.toList()).toString())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you can edit the `Message` class and whatever class `getMessageDetails` returns, I suggest that you override their `toString` methods (or write your own method that returns a string) instead:

```
// Message class:
public String toString() {
    return getText() + "-->" + getMessageDetails().toString();
}

// MessageDetails class
public String toString() {
    return "{" + getId() + ", " + getStatus() + "}";
}
```

Then you could just do:

```
messages.stream().map(Message::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
```